# Creating .Bat with many commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My concern is "how to create .bat file which will launch a couple of commands and save completed result into a HTML file"

I have next list of Windows (CMD) commands: Date, Time, Hostname, Net Accounts, Net Users, Net Group.

For example:

***When i type:***

```
Echo Net Accounts > C:\Users\PeKa\Documents\Document.HTML

Echo Net Group >> C:\Users\PeKa\Documents\Document.HTML
```

***I receive:***

> ```
> Force user logoff how long after time expires?:       Never
> Minimum password age (days):                          0
> Maximum password age (days):                          42
> Minimum password length:                              0
> Length of password history maintained:                None
> Lockout threshold:                                    Never
> Lockout duration (minutes):                           30
> Lockout observation window (minutes):                 30
> Computer role:                                        WORKSTATION
> The command completed successfully.
> ```

1-st problem is - I don't receive a command name (for this example it should be "Net Accounts")

2-nd problem is - I gain result only for the first command. - **Solved**

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Like: `@(echo Net Accounts& net accounts & echo Net Group& net group) > Document.html` to echo commands as titles?

Comment: `echo` is doing what `echo` is supposed to be doing - displaying text. That's all it does. If you want to store the output of a command, just run the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type:

```
Echo Net Accounts > C:\Users\PeKa\Documents\Document.HTML
```

You will create a file called "document.HTML" in the patch "C:\Users\PeKa\Documents\", which content will be a line like this:

> Net Accounts

The reason for that to happen is because **echo** is used to display messages. I guess that what you really want is to pipe **net accounts** results to a .html file, as well as for **net group**, which, by the way, can be used only on a Windows Domain Controller.

For your code to work, just eliminate echo. That's it. Here, with comments:

```
@echo off
rem Everytime you see a line that starts with REM or ::, it is a comment and won't be executed.
rem echo off will only type on the screen the relevant information, without the need to call the patch each time.

rem This will pipe the result of Net Accounts and Net Group execution to a file.
rem The use of > instead of >> will rewrite the whole document, if it exists.
Net Accounts > C:\Users\PeKa\Documents\Document.HTML
Net Group >> C:\Users\PeKa\Documents\Document.HTML

rem A pause just before your script ends will allow you to review any in screen message before it closes.
rem However, if an error takes place, the pause command will not avoid the script to close.
pause
```

The same script, without comments:

```
@echo off

Net Accounts > C:\Users\PeKa\Documents\Document.HTML
Net Group >> C:\Users\PeKa\Documents\Document.HTML

pause
```